# AudioInputStream not working once exported as jar/zip

Tags: java, maven, audio, export, mp3

so I am trying to play sound (mp3 files) via the mp3spi library. I should add that this project is meant to run inside another program, (like and add-on), so it does not itself have any main classes except for a debug class. When I run the project from this debug class, everything works fine, yet when running it from inside the main program (I should add that the add-on is exported as a jar and as zip file, the zip file will be loaded in the main program) I get a javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException. I think the issue has to do with the add-on not being correctly connected to the libraries, yet all the mp3spi jars are included in the lib folder.

We are using maven to build all the add-ons and the main program, so I also tried adding the class path to the manifest file. (In the maven-jar-plugin , like suggested in many other stack overflow posts) Somehow it seems to work for others, but not for me. Others also suggested to make the jar runnable, so I added the debug class as the main class and tried again, which did not work either.

Anyway, I am quite lost as I am running out of ideas to try. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the code that causes the error again:

```
 String path = soundFileMap.get(soundId);
    try {
        inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path));
    ... (rest not shown)
```

And here is the exception:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: format not supported
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStreamImpl(AudioSystem.java:1023) ~[tritonus share-0.3.7-2.jar:?]
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1005) ~[tritonus-share-0.3.7-2.jar:?]
    at jundl77.izou.izousound.outputplugin.SoundEngine.playSoundFile(SoundEngine.java:298) [classes/:?]
    at jundl77.izou.izousound.outputplugin.SoundEngine.run(SoundEngine.java:382) [classes/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_20]
```

And here is what my maven-jar-plugin looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Plugin-Id>${plugin.id}</Plugin-Id>
                <Plugin-Class>${plugin.class}</Plugin-Class>
                <Plugin-Version>${plugin.version}</Plugin-Version>
                <Plugin-Provider>${plugin.provider}</Plugin-Provider>
                <Plugin-Dependencies>${plugin.dependencies}</Plugin-Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>jundl77.izou.izousound.Debug</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Anyway, once again, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create the AudioInputStream directly from a URL or File, not an InputStream. Given that the resource is packed in a Jar, you should use URL, as one cannot read a file from within a jar.

Comment: Ok, the thing is though, that the sound file is not in the resource folder, the sound file should be able to lie anywhere on the system. Also the input stream is already an audio input stream. Also I think the issue has to do with java somehow referring to the default javax.sound.sampled library, and not the one that comes with tritonus, might that be it? And if so, do you know how I can communicate that to the compiler?

Comment: There is a known issue with using InputStream as an input to getAudioInputStream. If you consult the API for AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream, you will see when in InputStream is a parameter, added tests are made on the input file, e.g., markability, ability to reset. Audio files tend to fail these tests. The URL input parameter is the most robust, imho. AudioSystem IS javax.sound.sampled. I recommend you try this first, rule it out, before digging into Tritonus issues.

Comment: Ah thankyou! Turns out that didn't change anything :( But it's ok, I'm using the javafx media and mediaplayer now which ended up working, but thankyou for all the help! One quick question though if you know the answer, do you know if the mediaplayer streams the sound or does it buffer it all in? (In other words, is it relatively light on the system?)

Comment: I've never checked out the JavaFX audio. Glad to hear it is working for you! With Java, you can choose whether to stream (SourceDataLine) or load into memory first (Clip). The SourceDataLine initiates immediately, but processes the data in increments of some buffer amount (2K maybe, maybe more). With the Clip, the entire file has to be loaded into memory before it will start playing. I don't know if the JavaFX audio options are similar. Unpacking the mp3 of course add to the processing. It just depends whether you want to do it up front (Clip) or ongoing (SDL).